# How to move child element from one parent to another using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) plugin. I would like to move the search box (.dataTables_filter) and number of records to display dropdown (.dataTables_length) from their parent element (.dataTables_wrapper) to another div on my page without losing any registered javascript behavior. For instance the search box has a function attached to the 'keyup' event and I want to keep that intact.

The DOM looks like this:

```
<body>
<div id="parent1">
  <div class="dataTables_wrapper" id="table1_wrapper">
    <div class="dataTables_length" id="table1_length">
      <select size="1" name="table1_length">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="dataTables_filter" id="table1_filter">
      <input type="text" class="search">
    </div>
    <table id="table1">
    ...
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="parent2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link C</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

This is what I would like the DOM to look like after the move:

```
<body>
<div id="parent1">
  <div class="dataTables_wrapper" id="table1_wrapper">
    <table id="table1">
    ...
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="parent2">
  <div class="dataTables_filter" id="table1_filter">
    <input type="text" class="search">
  </div>
  <div class="dataTables_length" id="table1_length">
    <select size="1" name="table1_length">
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="25">25</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
      <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link C</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

I've been looking at the .append(), .appendTo(), .prepend() and .prependTo() functions but haven't had any luck with these in practice. I've also looked at the .parent() and .parents() functions, but can't seem to code a workable solution. I have also considered changing the CSS so that the elements are absolutely positioned - but to be frank the page is setup with fluid elements all over, and I really want these elements to be floated in their new parents.

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Comment: All the DOM manipulation functions you have listed should work just fine. Appending a DOM element to a different parent moves it to the new position keeping all the events intact. What exactly is not working for you? Is there an error?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`$('#parent2').prepend($('#table1_length')).prepend($('#table1_filter'));`

doesn't work for you? I think it should...

Comment: It was a naming problem. My example above works fine. The actual id's of the fields had multiple -'s and _'s in it, and I was not selecting the element because the id wasn't matching. Thank you.

Answer (score 386):

As Jage's answer removes the element completely, including event handlers and data, I'm adding a simple solution that doesn't do that, thanks to the [detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) function.

```
var element = $('#childNode').detach();
$('#parentNode').append(element);
```

**Edit:**

Igor Mukhin suggested an even shorter version in the comments below:

```
$("#childNode").detach().appendTo("#parentNode");
```

Comment: this is the best solution, because the detach()+append() won't clone the element but will move that to the new location. The events and the assocciated data won't get lost this way

Comment: this should be marked as answer.

Comment: Even shorter `$("#childNode").detach().appendTo("#parentNode");`

Comment: I use iimuhin's answer all the time. Simple. clean.

Comment: Except that you don't need detach. See my answer below.

Comment: @JackArbiter - `detach` was useful for me because I need to temporarily remove the children from the parent for processing, then put them back with their original parent (CPS-style), so while not useful in the question's instance (parent to adoptive parent) it did solve my problem ;)

Answer (score 178):

**`Detach` is unnecessary.**

The answer (as of 2013) is simple:

```
$('#parentNode').append($('#childNode'));
```

According to http://api.jquery.com/append/

> You can also select an element on the page and insert it into another:
>
> $('.container').append($('h2'));
>
> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location
>   elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned).

Comment: I found that detach gave me a different behavior in older browsers like IE (and even Edge). For example, Bootstraps DateTimePicker wouldn't work if the parent element was detached and appended, however simply using the append() to move my elements kept the DateTimePicker happy.

Answer (score 36):

Based on the answers provided, I decided to make a quick plugin to do this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.moveTo = function(selector){
        return this.each(function(){
            var cl = $(this).clone();
            $(cl).appendTo(selector);
            $(this).remove();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$('#nodeToMove').moveTo('#newParent');
```

Comment: This method clone the elements don't move them. specifically if you have store in a variable $('#nodeToMove') before the moveTo call it won't work anymore

Comment: @Jage why not use the JQuery syntax? $('#nodeToMove').appendTo('#newParent');  http://api.jquery.com/appendto/