# Setting the parent element of a jquery-ui window to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a standard jquery-ui dialog created with `$("#element").dialog();` and I'm trying to find the best way of containing it within the bounds of another element.

I'm trying to avoid doing it just with javascript and re-positioning it because I'd like to be able to move it outside the bounds of the container, and for the container to be able to scroll using `#container {overflow:auto;}`

Here's a fiddle of the situation: http://jsfiddle.net/Z4xAA/ - I'm trying to contain #myDialog within the bounds of #dialogContainer

I've tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596833/how-to-move-child-element-from-one-parent-to-another-using-jquery) to move the dialog.parent to the container element - but to no avail.

Any idea how I'd go about this?

Edit: I was playing around with the fiddle, and found that if I moved the dialog into the container element myself via the webkit debugger it behaved as desired. Now it's just a matter of doing that programatically.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. All that does is set the bounds the dialog can be moved within. But I want it to be properly contained within the element so it can be partially obscured and the parent element scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using .append() moves the element properly. Doing it on the .parent() of the dialog to the container gives the desired result.

```
$("#dialogContainer").append($("#myDialog").parent());
```

Updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Z4xAA/7/

All that needs doing after that is repositioning the dialog if needed to stop it being above the top of the element.