# Inserting a (g) node in the middle of a tree (SVG) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, svg, dom-manipulation

What is the most recommended/efficient way to insert a node in the middle of a tree.

How to transpose this

```
<svg id="root" ... >
  <g id="child1">...</g>
  <text id="child2">...</text>
  <rect id="child3">...</rect>
  ...
</svg>
```

to this

```
<svg id="root" ... >
  <g id="parent">
    <g id="child1">...</g>
    <text id="child2">...</text>
    <rect id="child3">...</rect>
    ...
  </g>
</svg>
```

[@jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/mxc2x/)

I have tried

```
var $parent = $("g").attr("id","parent");
var $root = $("#root");
$root.contents().each(function(){
   $child=$(this);
   $child.remove();
   $parent.append($child);
});
$root.append($parent);
```

I have also tried using the moveTo method in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596833/how-to-move-child-element-from-one-parent-to-another-using-jquery#answer-8727167) answer

```
(function($){
    $.fn.moveTo = function(selector){
        return this.each(function(){
            var cl = $(this).clone();
            $(cl).appendTo(selector);
            $(this).remove();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$root.contents().each(function() {
    $(this).moveTo($parent);
});
```

All of these methods work in simple scenarios but when the tree is really massive, the browser simply hangs, is there a more efficient way to perform this?
I am looking for a jQuery or pure javascript solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#root > div').wrapAll('<div id="parent" />');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZZ5ey/).

References:

- [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I wasn't aware about the wrapAll() method. It does the job of manipulating the DOM very effeciently, but the new element that I am wrapping around is a `g` element and the graphics doesn't show up after the manipulation [http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/mxc2x/2/]. If I manually (using firebug) edit the html to wrap the children of `svg` element around a `g` element everything works, i would assume the same should happen when done through javascript? The `g` shows up correctly inside the `svg` with all children moved but appears greyed out (like hidden elements) in firebug

Comment: Silly me, `$("#parent").show();` did the trick, but any idea why does it come up as hidden initially?

Comment: I honestly don't know; but mainly because I didn't want to wade through your demo. Um, sorry...I know, that sounds terrible... =(

Comment: No problem, I can understand :) Anyway it wasn't a part of the OP, may be I have a new question in hand ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will make only one addition to the DOM, so this will be fast :

```
$('#root').html('<div id=parent>'+$('#root').html()+'</div>');
```

Comment: You forgot parens after `$('#root').html` and this would most likely destroy any listeners and data bound to those elements.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have also added a jsFiddle example, its an svg element that I am trying to manipulate. Let me try your suggestion till you have a look at the fiddle