# Grouping SVG elements dynamically

Tags: jquery, dom, svg, dom-manipulation

I am trying to dynamically wrap certain `svg` elements like `rect`,`text`,etc into a single `g` using javascript (jQuery)

This is how the svg looks initially

```
<div id="container">
   <svg ...>
     <rect .../>
     <circle .../>
     <text ...>...</text>
   </svg>
</div>
```

The script (based on the helpful answers I received @ [Inserting a (g) node in the middle of a tree (SVG) using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547194/inserting-a-g-node-in-the-middle-of-a-tree-svg-using-jquery/12547219#12547219))  that I use to wrap into the `g` tag.

```
$("#container svg > *").wrapAll('<g id="parent" />');
```

The transformed `svg` looks like this

```
<div id="container">
   <g id="parent">
     <svg ...>
       <rect .../>
       <circle .../>
       <text ...>...</text>
     </svg>
   </g>
</div>
```

But nothing shows up on the UI. Even firebug shows the `g` to be grayed out (like it does for hidden elements).

[image]

calling `$("#parent").show();` works in [**sometime cases**](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/94xUT/) but [**not all**](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/mxc2x/3/)

**Questions:**

- Why does the `g` that is dynamically created, hidden by default?
- Why does `$("#parent").show()` work inconsistently?
- Is there another (better) way of grouping grouping elements dynamically?
- I am totally new to SVG, but relatively comfortable with jQuery and DOM manipulation. Is the way that I am treating SVG as just-another-tag wrong?

*Tried on both Firefox (15.0.1) and Chrome (21.0.1180.89) with same results*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason is due to the fact that the SVG is actually resides inside a different namespace to the containing HTML. When you pass a HTML fragment to JQuery (`<g id="parent" />` in your case) it is created in the namespace of the HTML document and not the SVG.

JQuery isn't really suited to creating and manipulating non-HTML elements, although you could achieve a half-way house by using a combination of native JavaScript + JQuery:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
    var $el = $(el);
    $el.attr('id', 'parent');
    $("#container svg > *").wrapAll($el);
});
```

I've previously used JQuery to successfully manipulate SVG elements using [Keith Wood's excellent JQuery plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html). You may want to take a look at that.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3642265/981208) discusses SVG and HTML namespaces in more detail.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm :) Good explanation around the namespace, i badly tried avoid the NS, that was my mistake i think. I did come across the svg plugin, but wanted to avoid it as this 1 line is the only svg that i need to do almost, I wanted to scale a group of svg elements at once, and hence had to wrap them around in a `g` that's all my use case. also thanks for the links!!