# Make element as parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an existing HTML as;

```
<div id="maincontent">
        <div id="firstname_lbl"></div>
        <div id="firstname_fld"></div>
</div>
```

I am creating a jQuery form dynamically as ;

```
$('<' + items.type + '/>').attr({
        "action": items.action,
         "name": items.name,
         "class": items.attributes.class
        })
```

Now I want this "form" element to become the parent of the existing "maincontent" div

So the DOM should then look like;

```
<form>
<div id="maincontent">
            <div id="firstname_lbl"></div>
            <div id="firstname_fld"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How do I do this using jQuery?

Also I am getting Expected identifier in IE for this line (works fine in Firefox);

```
var formEle = $('<' + items.type + '/>').attr({
        "action": items.action,
         "name": items.name,
         "class": items.attributes.class});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
var form = $("<" + items.type + "/>").attr({
    action: items.action,
    name: items.name,
    "class": items.attributes["class"]
});

$("#maincontent").wrap(form);
```

Comment: Thx a lot...Is there some chaining possible where I create the form ?

Comment: @testndtv Unfortunately there is no method like `wrapAround(smth)` in jQuery.

Comment: @testndtv: You can use `form.append($("#maincontent"))` and then go on chaining with form. Or you can use the `wrap` from above, but without an extra `form` variable.

Comment: @testndtv `class` is a reserved word in IE. That's why initially I've put `class` in quotes in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A great solution is provided here: [How to move child element from one parent to another using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596833/how-to-move-child-element-from-one-parent-to-another-using-jquery).

Here's the code:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.moveTo = function(selector){
        return this.each(function(){
            var cl = $(this).clone();
            $(cl).appendTo(selector);
            $(this).remove();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('#maincontent').moveTo('[FormSelectorHere]');
```