# How can I load Feedburner RSS dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, rss

My website is dynamic, so in a sense, the website is only one page, but that one page (Home Page) loads different content depending on links pressed, url changes, etc.. On my navigation bar, I have different links: about, blog, portfolio, resume, and contact. When I click on blog, I want to (1) load the `blog.html` code into the `body` of my Home Page and (2) execute the external javascript code that loads my blog RSS by Feedburner.

I've tried:

- `$.getScript(...);`
- creating a `script` tag dynamically
- `$(window).ready(...);`

**Note: I can't put the `script` tag in Home Page's `head` tag because wherever the `script` tag is, is where the external code is displayed (and I need it displayed in `<div class='content' id='blog-page'>`.**

Home Page:

```
<html>
   ...
   <body>   
      <div id="content"></div> <!-- Dynamic div -->

      <script>
         <!-- updateContent is called when URL changes, page loads, etc... -->
         function updateContent(page) {
            $('div#content').load('../../' + page + '.html');
         };
      </script>
   </body>  
</html>
```

Dynamic Content (pulled into Home Page):

```
<div class='content' id='blog-page'>
   <script src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogspot/bVDtI?format=sigpro" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
</div>
```

Any Ideas???? I'm at a total loss...

**Found the [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596833/how-to-move-child-element-from-one-parent-to-another-using-jquery)**

Answer (score 3):

That script uses document.write and has to be placed where the output is needed..

I suggest to use Google Feed API for dynamically reading the blog RSS/Atom like this

http://jsbin.com/UyoYOvO/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Data object: RSS feed URL, number of entries to return, result format, API version
        var data = {
            q: 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/video_and_audio/news_front_page/rss.xml'
            , num: 10
            , output: 'json'
            , v: '1.0'
        };

        // AJAX call to Google Feed API which converts ATOM/RSS feed to JSON
       $.ajax({
            url:'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load'
            ,type : "GET"
            ,dataType : "jsonp"
            ,data: data
            ,success: function (json) {
                var feed = json.responseData.feed;
                if(!feed) return;
                var entries = feed.entries;
                if(!entries) return;

                var html = '';
                for( var i=0; i<entries.length; i++){
                    html += '<h2><a href="'+ entries[i].link +'">'+ entries[i].title +'</a></h2>' +
                          '<p>'+ entries[i].contentSnippet +'</p>';
                };

                $('#output').html( html);
            }
      });
  })
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="output"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice example. Is three a way to display RSS/Atom in a full content on the blogger home page?

Comment: The Google Feed API is officially deprecated.