# How to move child element from one parent to another with animation (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, animation, append, detach

I made a toggle function that change the parent of a child element with some code from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596833/how-to-move-child-element-from-one-parent-to-another-using-jquery). But I want to know if there is a way to change the parent with animation, because now it just jump from one div to another.

[This is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlphaCrack/Pnq9f/)

Here is some code:

```
function SW()
{
    $("#SW").toggle(function(){
        var element = $("#RelativeChild").detach().appendTo("#ParentRight");
    },
    function(){
        var element = $("#RelativeChild").detach().appendTo("#ParentLeft");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
var element = $("#RelativeChild").hide('fade').detach().appendTo("#ParentRight")
.end().show('fade');
```

Full function:

```
function SW() {
    $("#SW").toggle(function () {
        var element = $("#RelativeChild").hide('fade').detach().appendTo("#ParentRight")
        .end().show('fade');
    },

    function () {
        var element = $("#RelativeChild").hide('fade').detach().appendTo("#ParentLeft")
        .end().show('fade');
    });
}
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Pnq9f/2/)