# How to show popup on top of child window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popupwindow

A is Parent application and B is child application .

B will be launched from A . when there is session timeout in application A , i need to show intimation popup . I can show the popup on top of Application A (parent window ). lets say user is using application B (Child window) then they do not know that popup got displayed in application A (parent window) . So i want to show pop on child window which is B .

the solution which i am expecting is  how to show popup on top of current application which can be A (parent window  ) or B (Child window) .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Show us some code, what you have tried!!

Comment: i have tried to invoke the function which is in child window from parent window . but getting cross domain error while invoking that method .

Comment: that child window function will show the popup on top of child window

Comment: var childwindow = window.open(''sample.html')

Comment: childwindow.callme()

Comment: child window       function callme (){ alet("session timeout") }

Comment: First thinking, you can change the current popup window's parent in jquery, and use z-index: 1000 then change it back to the previous parent. have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596833/how-to-move-child-element-from-one-parent-to-another-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

[window.focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus) should bring your popup window to foreground, independent from the opener's position.